# How can I add text below the nav bar and all that?

Tags: html, css, text, header, nav

I am trying to add text below my header/nav bar. Please see code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width", initial-scale="1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
        <title>How to use the Print Tool</title>
    
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div>
<header>
            <a href="https://ecj.com.jm/"> <img src="../img/ecjLogo.png"  id="logo"> </a>
            <div class="name"> Business</div>

            <input type="checkbox" id="menu-bar">
            <label fr="menu-bar">Menu</label>

            <nav class="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li> <a href="#">Application</a></li>
                    <li> <a href="#"> Help </a></li>
                    <li> <a href="#"> About </a></li>
                    <li> <a href="#"> Contact </a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>


        </header>

        </div>
        

 <div>
    <h1>Geographic Information Systems (GIS) Department - ECJ Web Map Ver. 2.0 </h1>

<p> hello

 </div>
</p>
       
    </body>
</html>
```

```css
*{
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    text-decoration: none;
}
body{
    background: #dee1e2;
    min-height: 100vh;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
header{
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    padding: 20px 7%;
    display: flex;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    z-index: 1000;
}
header .name{
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #333
}
header .navbar ul{
    list-style: none;
}
header .navbar ul li{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
header .navbar ul li a{
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    color: #333;
    display: block;
}
header .navbar ul li a:hover{
    background: #333;
    color: #fff;
}
header .navbar ul li ul{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 200px;
    background: #fff;
}

#menu-bar{
    display: none;
}
header label{
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #333;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
}
h1{
    color: #333;
}
@media(max-width:991px){
    header{
        padding: 20px;
    }

    header label{
        display: initial;
    }

    header .navbar{
        position: absolute;
        top:100%;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        background: #fff;
        border-top: 1 px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
    }

    header .navbar ul li{
        width: 100%;
    }

    header .navbar ul li ul{
        position: relative;
        width: 100%
    }

    #menu-bar:checked ~ .navbar{
        display: initial;
    }
}
```

I have tried putting the navigation bar in a div. I have tried changing font color. None of that has worked. I would like to add code now below the navigation bar. I have added the css and html code for reference and assistance. Yeah so if you could assist it would be really nice.

Comment: It looks like you have included a stylesheet (`styles.css`), so please also provide the necessary css code for your navbar/header/..., otherwise your problem isn't reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

What's happening with you is normal since the header is `fixed`, thus anything that will follow (and which does not have a special position set) will be hidden behind it.

A workaround that you can do is give a `margin-top` value to the elements that follow your header (I put them in a `<main>` tag):

```css
main {
  margin-top: 350px;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  text-decoration: none;
}
body {
  background: #dee1e2;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  z-index: 1000;
}
header .name {
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #333;
}
header .navbar ul {
  list-style: none;
}
header .navbar ul li {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}
header .navbar ul li a {
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #333;
  display: block;
}
header .navbar ul li a:hover {
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
}
header .navbar ul li ul {
  /*     position: absolute; */
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  background: #fff;
}

#menu-bar {
  display: none;
}
header label {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #333;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
}
h1 {
  color: #333;
}
@media (max-width: 991px) {
  main {
    margin-top: 80px;
  }
  header {
    padding: 20px;
  }

  header label {
    display: initial;
  }

  header .navbar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: #fff;
    border-top: 1 px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  }

  header .navbar ul li {
    width: 100%;
  }

  header .navbar ul li ul {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
  }

  #menu-bar:checked ~ .navbar {
    display: initial;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <a href="https://ecj.com.jm/"> <img src="../img/ecjLogo.png" id="logo"> </a>
  <div class="name"> Business</div>

  <input type="checkbox" id="menu-bar">
  <label fr="menu-bar">Menu</label>

  <nav class="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li> <a href="#">Application</a></li>
      <li> <a href="#"> Help </a></li>
      <li> <a href="#"> About </a></li>
      <li> <a href="#"> Contact </a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

</header>

<main>
  <div>
    <h1>Geographic Information Systems (GIS) Department - ECJ Web Map Ver. 2.0 </h1>

    <p> hello </p>
  </div>
</main>
```